# Add GDAL tools to QGIS 3.12.1

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, qgis-3

I have QGIS 3.12.1 which doesn't have any GDAL options in the Raster Menu. Also in the Plug-In menu I cannot find GDAL. Does any know how I can add this?

[image]

Comment: The GDAL tools are in the Processing Toolbox panel which is where you also set configuration options, although in the case of GDAL you merely activate it or not there.  Parameters are set in the tools themselves.

Comment: Could you go to `Menu > Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins` to open the Plugins Manager? There on the `Installed` tab, find **Processing**. If it is unchecked, tick it on.

Comment: Processing was checked already, but thank you anyway. The comment of Johns really helped! I think I found everything I need now :)